# Cant read data from XML file in Java with JAVAXB

Tags: java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fields")
public class Employee {

        String Empname;
        String EmpID;
        String salary;
    //  @XmlElement
        Employee()
        {}
        Employee(String Empname, String EmpID,String salary)
        {  super(); 
                this.Empname=Empname;
                this.EmpID=EmpID;
                this.salary=salary;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public String getID()
        {
            return EmpID;
        }
        @XmlElement
        public void setEmployeeDetails(String Empname, String EmpID,String salary)
        {
            this.Empname=Empname;
            this.EmpID=EmpID;
            this.salary=salary;

        }


    } 


public class EmployeeProcess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            File file = new File("/EmployeePosition/src/EmployeeDemo/EmployeeMainData.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);  
             Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller(); 
         Employee que= (Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);  
               System.out.println(que.getID());  

        }



         catch (JAXBException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
              }  
        }

} 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fields>
    <EmpName>ABC</EmpName>
    <EmpID>319501</EmpID>
    <salary>15000</salary>
</fields>
```

Getting error like this

```
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(namespace=##default, name=##default, type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement$DEFAULT, required=false, defaultValue=

at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at EmployeeDemo.EmployeeProcess.main(EmployeeProcess.java:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class should be something like this. Give @xmlElement to fields and remove @xmlElement from setEmployeeDetails method. By default access type is for public member, so you can change access modifier of EmpId to public which will work without @XmlElement.

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "fields")
 public class Employee {

    String Empname;
    @XmlElement
    String EmpID;
    String salary;
//  @XmlElement
    Employee()
    {}
    Employee(String Empname, String EmpID,String salary)
    {  super(); 
            this.Empname=Empname;
            this.EmpID=EmpID;
            this.salary=salary;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getID()
    {
        return EmpID;
    }
    public void setEmployeeDetails(String Empname, String EmpID,String salary)
    {
        this.Empname=Empname;
        this.EmpID=EmpID;
        this.salary=salary;

    }




}
```